# Running web.py on Dreamhost

Tags: python, web.py, dreamhost, fastcgi

I am trying to set up web.py on Dreamhost using this guide:
[Web.py - Dreamhost Wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Web.py)

My problem is that many pages on this topic refers to fcgi.py and links to a svn repository that no longer exists. So I got flup instead, and I can run

```
import web
from flup.server import fcgi
```

without errors in Python, but not `import fcgi`

The `flup.server` version of `fcgi` can't stand alone, so I can't simply copy the one file somewhere into the PYTHONPATH.

When I try open index.py `500 Internal server error`. I tried to check out the logs, but they are note very useful - all I get there is `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200`.

I have run out of ideas how to debug this thing.